# Make Filter by one or more parameters

Tags: c#, console-application

I have `List<Book> Books`

```cs
public class Book
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Author { get; set; }
    public string Category { get; set; }
    public string Language { get; set; }
    public DateTime Publication_date { get; set; }
    public string ISBN { get; set; }
}
```

tried this, but it only work if all parameters matched

```cs
foreach (var item in Books)
{
    if ((!string.IsNullOrEmpty(name) && item.Name == name) 
      && (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(author) && item.Author == author) 
      && (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(category) && item.Category == category)
      && (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(language) && item.Language == language) 
      && (Publication_date.HasValue && item.Publication_date == Publication_date) 
      && (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ISBN) && item.ISBN == ISBN))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item);
    }
}
```

how to make filter by one or more parameters? like if i enter only "name" and "Language" it will print me the book where both parameters a matched (if string is null or empty then parameter should be skipped)

Thanks)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The logic is a touch complicated, but made simpler by use of `continue`.

```
foreach (var item in Books)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(name) && item.Name != name) continue;
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(author) && item.Author != author) continue;
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(category) && item.Category != category) continue;
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(language) && item.Language != language) continue;
    if (Publication_date.HasValue  && item.Publication_Date != Publication_Date) continue;
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ISBN) && item.ISBN!= ISBN) continue;

    Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```

Comment: A question about the logic - if, for example, the `name` matches so it moves on to `author ` which doesn't and therefore hits the `continue` and move to the next item in the list. Now, if `category` matches too but it won't get around to check it since it jumped to the next item in the list...so in this logic, is it possible to have for example only `author` and `ISBN` (or any other random combination of properties for that matter) matched?

Comment: This code will output an item only if it matches all supplied parameters. Does that answer your question?

Comment: Yes it does. I may have misunderstood the op question...Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

you want it in a form where each condition returns true if null, or true if match.  Basically null/empty means anything is a match

like

```
(string.IsNullOrEmpty(name) || item.Name == name)
```

then && them altogether

```
foreach (var item in Books)
{
    if ((string.IsNullOrEmpty(name) || item.Name == name) 
      && (string.IsNullOrEmpty(author) || item.Author == author) 
      && (string.IsNullOrEmpty(category) || item.Category == category)
      && (string.IsNullOrEmpty(language) || item.Language == language) 
      && (!Publication_date.HasValue || item.Publication_date == Publication_date) 
      && (string.IsNullOrEmpty(ISBN) || item.ISBN == ISBN))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item);
    }
}
```

to be a little clearer you can do

```
bool IsMatchForFilter(string filter, string value) 
       => string.IsNullOrEmpty(filter) || filter == value;
```

then do

```
if(
   IsMatchForFilter(name, item.Name) 
   && IsMatchForFilter(author, item.Author)
  ...
```

Answer (score -1):

Try it like this, use the `OR` (`||`) operator

```cs
foreach (var item in Books)
{
    if ((!string.IsNullOrEmpty(name) && item.Name == name) 
      || (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(author) && item.Author == author) 
      || (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(category) && item.Category == category)
      || (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(language) && item.Language == language) 
      || (Publication_date.HasValue && item.Publication_date == Publication_date) 
      || (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ISBN) && item.ISBN == ISBN))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: it will return me any book that will match one of parameters if i enter name:aaa and author: Author (Name: aaa Author: aaaaa Category: aaaaaa Language: aaaaaaa Publication_date: 2019/5/1 ISBN: 7804363458168
Name: Name Author: Author Category: Category Language: Language Publication_date: 2020/2/2 ISBN: 4654561451668)